# Transferring Cordova debug build to real phone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

After running this command, the terminal says build succeeded,

```
ionic cordova build ios --debug
```

Can I transfer the build in my device? How to install it? 
I am new to ios ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run:

```
ionic cordova run ios --debug
```

Referring to Documentation of ionic https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/run/

Anyway, if that was not helpful, simply you can open Xcode project from the build that you made, and run debug inside Xcode.

If you mean deploying it to Apple store, then you need to look into this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/#ios-devices

Comment: I get code signing error if the device is connected, otherwise it runs successfully in the emulator

Comment: I selected the provisioning profile given by my teammate in xcode before running the command - ionic cordova run ios --debug. The error is Provisioning profile "eps-dev" doesn't include any certificate for which the matching private key is installed in the keychain. He also gave me the certificate, but don't know what to do with it. I added the certificate to keychain, but it did not work ..

Comment: Have you tried using Xcode? to be honest, personally, I never succeeded to run the ionic app from the command line, I always use Xcode, to fix these annoying provision profiles and certificates.

Comment: In xcode i get the same cert error, even for emulators

Comment: thanks for your effort. I could solve the issue. In fact, xcode was right, the cert was made without the needed private key. My teammate made the cert again and I could run on device from xcode.